# My Foreach Loop loops through a list of ChildNodes under a Main Node, and only selects the firstNode

Tags: c#, xml, foreach, selectsinglenode, selectnodes

I'm trying to loop through a list of ChildNodes under a main node, and I have the list of ChildNodes in a XMLNodeList. I've successfully looped through it, and that part of the code works, but it will only select the firstnode of the NodeList as I'm using SelectSingleNode. I need a work-around for this problem, to loop through every single XML node in the NodeList and select some child attributes from it. I've unsuccessfully tried to delete each node as I'm going through it, I've looked into SelectNodes a little bit, but they all have the same name; the only real difference is the date. Any suggestions?

Code:

```
XmlNode TransactionMain = XMLFromServer.SelectSingleNode("");
XmlNodeList TransactionsNodeList = TransactionMain.ChildNodes;
foreach(XmlNode TransactionsSingleNode in TransactionsNodeList) {
    //Finding all of the pertinent information for the Transactions table from EACH node (note the foreach loop) inside the bigger Transaction node
    string SalesTaxAmount = TransactionsSingleNode.SelectNodes("").Value;
    string PaymentAmount = TransactionsSingleNode.SelectSingleNode("").Value;
    string RecurringProfileID = TransactionsSingleNode.SelectSingleNode("").Value;
    string TransactedDateTime = TransactionsSingleNode.SelectSingleNode("").Value;
    string NumberOfDays = TransactionsSingleNode.SelectSingleNode("").Value;
    string LicenseSizeDescriptionTransactionsList = TransactionsSingleNode.SelectSingleNode("").Value;
    Transactions.Rows.Add(CompanyName, SalesTaxAmount, PaymentAmount, RecurringProfileID, TransactedDateTime, NumberOfDays, LicenseSizeDescriptionTransactionsList);
```

The CompanyName variable comes from another place, that works fine. e
I've removed the XPath expressions, as it contained a bit of private information. If it's necessary I can put them back in.
XML:

```
<Authorization LicenseDaysLeft="22" LicenseEndDate="2018-11-17" LicenseSizeDescription="" LicenseSizeCode="1">
  <Paypal LastEmailUsed="" RecurringProfileID="" LastTransactionDateTime="">
     <Transactions>
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2018-10-18 07:54" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2018-09-18 08:19" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2018-08-19 00:38" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2018-07-20 09:16" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2018-06-20 01:24" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2018-05-21 09:06" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2018-04-19 08:31" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2018-03-13 08:58" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2018-02-11 08:22" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2018-01-17 10:22" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2017-12-13 10:08" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2017-11-13 12:04" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2017-10-14 10:18" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2017-09-20 07:14" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2017-08-22 23:52" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2017-07-21 08:36" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2017-06-24 08:58" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2017-05-24 11:24" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2017-04-17 16:42" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2017-03-18 09:02" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2017-02-16 15:08" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2017-01-23 09:13" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2016-12-24 18:07" NumberOfDays="30" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2016-11-23 16:09" NumberOfDays="0" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2016-10-24 14:37" NumberOfDays="0" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2016-09-24 15:58" NumberOfDays="0" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
        <Transaction SalesTaxAmount="0.00" PaymentAmount="0.00" RecurringProfileID="" TransactedDateTimeUTC="0001-01-01 00:00" TransactedDateTime="2016-08-25 16:48" NumberOfDays="0" LicenseSize="0" LicenseSizeDescription="" />
     </Transactions>
  </Paypal>
 </Authorization>
```

Trying to loop through each Transaction and add it to a table. It will only select the first one.

Comment: Using the newer library XML Linq usually gets better results.  You didn't post the xml so I really can't help.

Answer (score -1):

It is very simple with xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("SalesTaxAmount", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("PaymentAmount", typeof(decimal)); 
            dt.Columns.Add("RecurringProfileID", typeof(string)); 
            dt.Columns.Add("TransactedDateTimeUTC", typeof(DateTime)); 
            dt.Columns.Add("TransactedDateTime", typeof(DateTime)); 
            dt.Columns.Add("NumberOfDays", typeof(int)); 
            dt.Columns.Add("LicenseSize", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("LicenseSizeDescription=", typeof(string));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            foreach(XElement transaction in doc.Descendants("Transaction"))
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    (decimal?)transaction.Attribute("SalesTaxAmount"),
                    (decimal?)transaction.Attribute("PaymentAmount"),
                    (string)transaction.Attribute("RecurringProfileID"),
                    (DateTime)transaction.Attribute("TransactedDateTimeUTC"),
                    (DateTime)transaction.Attribute("TransactedDateTime"),
                    (int?)transaction.Attribute("NumberOfDays"),
                    (int)transaction.Attribute("LicenseSize"),
                    (string)transaction.Attribute("LicenseSizeDescription")
                });

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help, late response as I've been busy with school. It took a little bit to adapt the code, but it worked; I just needed to run a function at the end of the code to change all nulls into a parsable string for the web browser.

Comment: Are you referring to the integers and decimal nulls?  Do you want them to be zero?   Or maybe make values strings instead of number.

Comment: I managed to get it working. Had to do half of the loop in Linq, in XElement, and the other half in c#.